# I have a widget that I want to use in multiple routes. I need this widget to use different custom class instances depending on which route it is

Tags: flutter, class, widget, instance

The widget always uses the instance which is in it's own dart file. I want to create different instances on each route and have the widget use that exact instance.

My custom class (I only need the name right now):

```
class Chat {
String name, lastMesssage, image, time, page;
bool isActive;

Chat ({
  this.name,
  this.lastMesssage,
  this.image,
  this.time,
  this.isActive,
  this.page,
});
}
```

My widget:

```
Chat chat;

class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarState createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: 15,),
        Image(image: AssetImage("assets/asset.png"), width: 55, height: 55,),
        SizedBox(width: 10,),
        Column(
          children: [
            //that's where I need different Chat instances
            Text(chat.name, style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 25,
            ),),
            Text("Online", style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              fontSize: 15,
            ),),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 0,width: 85,),
        Icon(Icons.call_rounded, color: Colors.blueGrey, size: 45, ),
        SizedBox(height:0, width: 14),
        Icon(Icons.videocam, color: Colors.blueGrey, size: 45, ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Where I need the widget (I want Bar() to use michael scott inside it, for instance):

```
Chat chat = Chat(name: michael scott);

return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 30,),
          Bar(), 
          //It goes on
```

Comment: Can you post you navigation code ?just to see if you are using named routes or another approach

Comment: `void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: "/chatScreen",
    routes: {
      "/home":(context) => Home(),
      "/chatScreen":(context) => ChatScreen(),
      "/chatScreenA":(context)=> ChatScreenA(),
      "/chatScreenB ":(context)=> ChatScreenB(),
      "/chatScreenD":(context)=> ChatScreenD(),
      "/chatScreenC":(context)=> ChatScreenC(),
      "/winScreen":(context)=> WinScreen(),
    },
  ));
}`

This is my main.dart file. I also have imports at the top.

Comment: Refer to https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments for more details about passing variables using route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass that exact `Chat` instance when navigation to the `Bar` route. In that case, you have to options.

**1. Taking the `Chat` argument in the `Bar` constuctor**

```
class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Chat chat;

  const Bar({Key? key, required this.chat}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BarState createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 15,
        ),
        Image(
          image: AssetImage("assets/asset.png"),
          width: 55,
          height: 55,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            //that's where I need different Chat instances
            Text(
              chat.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Online",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[600],
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 0,
          width: 85,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.call_rounded,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          size: 45,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 0, width: 14),
        Icon(
          Icons.videocam,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          size: 45,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of Bar with a specific Chat instance, like this:

```
Bar(
  chat: Chat(
    //Fill the rest of the properties
  ),
),
```

If you want to navigate to another route with this Bar instance, you will use the following:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Bar(chat: Chat())),
),
```

**2. Passing the chat argument with named route**

In this case we don't take the argument from the contractor, we use the following method from the Navigator class instead:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/bar', arguments: Chat());
```

In order to this method work properly, we should also add the `onGenerateRoute` callback to the MaterialApp in the root of the application. Like this:

```
 MaterialPageRoute? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  if (settings.name == '/bar') {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Bar(), settings: settings);
  }
}

MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: onGenerateRoute,
)
```

After navigating to the Bar, we have to retrieve the arguments that are passed to the route. Usually this is done in the first line of the `build` method of the widget. In this case, the Bar widget will look like this:

```
class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Bar({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _BarState createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final chat = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Chat;
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 15,
        ),
        Image(
          image: AssetImage("assets/asset.png"),
          width: 55,
          height: 55,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            //that's where I need different Chat instances
            Text(
              chat.name,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Online",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[600],
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 0,
          width: 85,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.call_rounded,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          size: 45,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 0, width: 14),
        Icon(
          Icons.videocam,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          size: 45,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! First method saved me a lot of code duplication. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as the correct answer so that other people can benefit from it.